# How do I fix the resource leak in my RSA algorithm (java)?

Tags: java, rsa, java.util.scanner, resource-leak

I am attempting to make an RSA algorithm and i'm not sure how to close my scanner. I have attempted to use `.close();` for instance trying to place it at the end of my RSA class but to no avail. Most likley I am just not putting it in the correct place or because i keep getting the following error in Visual Studio on my line 19:

[image]

Help much appreciated.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class RSA {
    static int gcd(int m, int n) {
        while (n != 0) {
            int r = m % n;
            m = n;
            n = r;
        }
        return m;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int p = 0, q = 0, n = 0, e = 0, d = 0, phi = 0;
        int nummes[] = new int[100];
        int encrypted[] = new int[100];
        int decrypted[] = new int[100];
        int i = 0, j = 0, nofelem = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String message;
        System.out.println("Enter the Message to be encrypted:");
        message = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter value of p and q\n");
        p = sc.nextInt();
        q = sc.nextInt();
        n = p * q;
        phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
        for (i = 2; i < phi; i++)
            if (gcd(i, phi) == 1) break;
        e = i;
        for (i = 2; i < phi; i++)
            if ((e * i - 1) % phi == 0) break;
        d = i;
        for (i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            char c = message.charAt(i);
            nummes[i] = c - 96;
        }
        nofelem = message.length();
        for (i = 0; i < nofelem; i++) {
            encrypted[i] = 1;
            for (j = 0; j < e; j++)
                encrypted[i] = (encrypted[i] * nummes[i]) % n;
        }
        System.out.println("\n Encrypted message\n");
        for (i = 0; i < nofelem; i++) {
            System.out.print(encrypted[i]);
            System.out.print((char) (encrypted[i] + 96));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < nofelem; i++) {
            decrypted[i] = 1;
            for (j = 0; j < d; j++)

                decrypted[i] = (decrypted[i] * encrypted[i]) % n;
        }
        System.out.println("\n Decrypted message\n ");
        for (i = 0; i < nofelem; i++)
            System.out.print((char) (decrypted[i] + 96));
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ignore it. That warning is not relevant in the context of a `Scanner` that wraps `System.in`. If you feel compelled to not ignore it, use a `try-with-resources`. `try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {` and add the closing `}` at the end.

Comment: I tried that out but ended up getting more errors. Also i would like to ignore it but visual studio wont run the program until I resolve the error.

Comment: That is a warning, not an error.